# A directed version of strongly regular graphs

Tags: spectral-graph-theory

Strongly Regular Graphs (SRGs) can be defined as $k$-regular graphs with exactly two distinct eigenvalues different from $k.$

Define Strongly Regular Digraphs (SRDs) as $k$-regular *digraphs* with exactly two distinct eigenvalues different from $k.$ Can we characterize
SRDs?

For instance DSRG (Directed Strongly Regular Graphs) as defined by Duval  are SRDs. Is the converse true?